# Remaining icon in PreferencePanes

Tags: system-settings

I succesfully removed some unneeded fuse apps but 'fuse-ext2' icon remained in System Preferences pane. If I right-click and ask for Remove I get an error message:

> The “fuse-ext2” preferences pane could not be removed because an error occurred.

How to remove this icon?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was faced with the same lingering preference pane (specifically for fuse-ext2).

I took two steps to finally be able to remove the preference pane. All of the preference pane locations mentioned in the Apple [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/PreferencePanes/Concepts/Anatomy.html) contained no mention of the preference pane in question.

What I found was one potentially relevant preference pane in a cache and the preference pane cache itself.

To clear the preference pane cache, just move the `~/Library/Caches/com.apple.preferencepanes.cache` file to the trash or delete it by some other means. This may be all that you need to fix the issue. If it's not...

I also removed a file (`~/Library/Caches/com.github.osxfuse.OSXFUSEPrefPane`) that could have been relevant, but may not have been. I removed the file before clearing the preference pane cache, so I'm unable to say which definitively solved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

If you navigate to the two folders below, you should be able to delete the file using Finder:

- ~/Library/PreferencePanes
- /Library/PreferencePanes

Just use the Finder go menu and select **Go to Folder...** for the above locations.

Comment: I already tried that, but amazingly, there is no prefPane file related to this app. It seems like a ghost.

Any idea?!?